# Constraining Higher-Kinded Types in Scala

Tags: scala, types

Say I have a higher kinded type

```
SuperMap[Key[_],Value[_]]`.
```

Suppose now that I had something even more specific that required that the type parameter for `Key` must match that for `Value`; that is, something like:

```
SuperDuperMap[T, Key[T], Value[T]]
```

Further suppose that I didn't want just any `T`, but a very specific one where `T <: OtherT`

```
SuperDuperPooperMap[T <: OtherT, Key[T], Value[T]]
```

Can this be done in Scala?  Is this just generally a bad idea?  Is there an equivalent way of doing this that's easier to read/write/use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your declaration already works as supposed to, i.e. you're restricting the type of `T` as well as `Key` and `Value`. The way you've written it, however, scala will complain if you issue something like

```
scala> class Foo[T <: OtherT, Key[T], Value[T]]
defined class Foo

scala> new Foo[SpecialOtherT, Key[SpecialOtherT], Value[SpecialOtherT]]
<console>:13: error: Key[SpecialOtherT] takes no type parameters, expected: one
              new Foo[SpecialOtherT, Key[SpecialOtherT], Value[SpecialOtherT]]
```

because the types of both `Key` and `Value` are already given by your former declaration. Hence this will work

```
scala> new Foo[SpecialOtherT, Key, Value]
res20: Foo[SpecialOtherT,Key,Value] = Foo@3dc6a6fd
```

which is probably not want you want. You could do it like this

```
scala> class Foo[T <: OtherT, K <: Key[T], V <: Value[T]]
defined class Foo

scala> new Foo[SpecialOtherT, Key[SpecialOtherT], Value[SpecialOtherT]]
res21: Foo[SpecialOtherT,Key[SpecialOtherT],Value[SpecialOtherT]] = Foo@7110506e
```

At the bottom line, since the types of `Key` and `Value` depend solely on `T` it is somewhat superfluous to have all that redundant information when working with `Foo`. So why not use an inner type declaration like so:

```
class Foo[T <: OtherT] {
  type K = Key[T]
  type V = Value[T]
}
```

Then you'd have access to types `K` and `V` from within the class but wouldn't need to type it everytime you create a new answer:

```
scala> new Foo[SpecialOtherT]
res23: Foo[SpecialOtherT] = Foo@17055e90

scala> new Foo[Int]
<console>:11: error: ...
```

Comment: Thanks!  Very informative.  My only answer to "So why not use an inner type declaration" is that I want to have those types for K and V inferred on instantiation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand because the type actually is inferred. Depending on your use-case, you can still use the type from the "outside", e.g. `class Foo[T]; class Bar[T] { type Wee = Foo[T] }; def doSomething[T](b: Bar[T])(implicit mf: Manifest[Bar[T]#Wee]) { Console println mf }`, and then `doSomething(new Bar[Double])`. Agreed, it's a dirty example.

Answer (score 3):

*Can this be done in Scala?*

What do you mean? You just did!

*Is this just generally a bad idea?*

Why would it be? In fact that's a great idea! This is what higher-kinded types are for.

*Is there an equivalent way of doing this that's easier to read/write/use?*

**Reading** - reads pretty well to me.

**Writing** - write/test/compile once, use everywhere.

**Using** - The compiler will reconstruct (infer) the types "everywhere".

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need anything more complicated than a couple of type aliases,

```
type SuperDuperMap[T, Key[_], Value[_]] = SuperMap[Key, Value]

type SuperDuperPooperMap[T <: OtherT, Key[_], Value[_]] = SuperMap[Key, Value]
```

Sample REPL session,

```
scala> new SuperDuperMap[Int, Option, List] {}
res0: java.lang.Object with SuperDuperMap[Int,Option,List] = ...

scala> new SuperDuperPooperMap[OtherT, Option, List] {}
res1: java.lang.Object with SuperDuperPooperMap[OtherT,Option,List] = ...
```